# @classmethod not updating class instance attributes in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was expecting the "maintanenance_freq" attribute of the instance value to change to 6, However I do not see it happening. It shows 12. Am I missing something here?

---

```
import datetime

class car():

    def __init__(self, color,make,model,year,maintanenance_freq):
        self.color=color
        self.make=make
        self.model=model
        self.year=year
        self.maintanenance_freq=maintanenance_freq

    def vehicle_age(self):
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        return(now.year-self.year)

    @classmethod
    def maintenance_window_cls(cls,window):
        cls.maintanenance_freq = window
        return cls.maintanenance_freq

car1= car("Green","Honda","Accord",2014,12)
car2= car("White","Lexus","NX",2017,12)


car.maintenance_window_cls(6)

print(car2.maintanenance_freq)
```

Comment: _Am I missing something here_ Yes, you are confusing class attributes with instance attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing class attributes with instance attributes.

In this class, `race` is a class attribute, and `name` and `age` are instance attributes:

```
class Person(object):
    race = "human"
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
```

Each instance of `Person` has its own separate values for `name` and `age`, and all instances share one value for `race`.

In your example, you're setting a class attribute of the same name as an instance attribute, which is mostly useless because instance attributes take precedence over class attributes of the same name.

`car.maintanenance_freq` (the class attribute) is set to 6, but `car2.maintanenance_freq` (the instance attribute) is still 12.